# How do I break out of jQuery .submit() loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What i am trying to accomplish is to check weather a coupon code is applied on my application, and submit the form to apply the coupon if it has not been applied yet. However the console log continues to report null and not submit the form.

```js
if(document.getElementById("#vapsummarycolcoupon").innerHTML== null) {
      $( "#activatecoupon" ).submit();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
}
```

When the form is submitted, the page will reload and have a new element with id="vapsummarycolcoupon" so to break from the page constantly submitting I have tried to check if the innerHTML != "$ 5.00" as well as == "undefined" and == null but with no luck. Something must be wrong, or there is a better way to accomplish this task. Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you please provide the full example?

Comment: <span class="vapsummarycouponvalue" id="vapsummarycolcoupon">$ -5.00</span>
 This is the code that appears after the form submits, but with this if statement it does not even pass the if statement check.

Comment: Please add the wrapping javascript as well. Like this, there is no function, so the return doesnt make sense.

Comment: I added this in script tags and into a seperate function testCode{ } which i then call at the bottom of the page with testCode(); but same result. Maybe there is a way to submit the form without running the if statement and not looping infinite?

Comment: I have added the answer below, if you down voted me please undo it as this can help people. Check the answer as correct too please.

Comment: Stop asking people to undo their votes everywhere. You receive downvotes on a question when it shows a lack of research or effort, which this question clearly shows. Had you bothered to even look up [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) you'd have seen that it will never return `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reversing the if statement, i was actually able to resolve the issue as well as check the length instead. Thanks for trying people, down voting cause you couldnt resolve the issue is sad.

```
$( window ).load(function() {
 if($("#vapsummarycolcoupon").length > 0 ) {
return null;
} else{
 $( "#activatecoupon" ).submit();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") 
{
    alert("Browser doesn't support Storage");
} 
else 
{
    var X = document.getElementById("#vapsummarycolcoupon").innerHTML;
    if(X == "") 
    {
        if(sessionStorage.getItem("submit") != true)
        {
            sessionStorage.setItem("submit", true);
            $( "#activatecoupon" ).submit();
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Already Submitted");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you i will try now

Comment: i am getting a console log "type error / is null" for this line , var X = document.getElementById("#vapsummarycolcoupon").innerHTML;

Comment: Make sure that you have added the latest version of Jquery. 1) check script tag, it should be type="text/javascript" 2) Put your codes inside ready function.

Comment: Use, var X = $("#vapsummarycolcoupon").html(); instead.

Comment: Ive checked script tag, and ive tried putting inside the ready/window load function. Also .html() is giving same result :( is there any other way to submit the form without looping infinite?

Comment: <span class="vapsummarycouponvalue" id="vapsummarycolcoupon">$ -5.00</span>

$( window ).load(function() {
    if($("#vapsummarycolcoupon").innerHTML== null) {
  $( "#activatecoupon" ).submit();
} else {
  return null;
}
});

Comment: Which browser are you using ? Make sure that you are using latest browser with coding in HTML5.

Comment: firefox 49.0.1 up to date

Comment: Which version of HTML are you using. Did you check it on Chrome ?

Comment: I cannot use local storage even if it worked because if the user clears the shopping cart then it wont apply the coupon when they re add items.. Thanks for the suggestion. Would switching the method of post to get do something? Or some other form of submit that doesnt refresh the page like ajax?

Comment: I have added the answer below, if you down voted me please undo it as this can help people. Check the answer as correct too please.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if($("#vapsummarycolcoupon").innerHTML== null) {
  $( "#activatecoupon" ).submit();
} else {
  return null;
}
```

Comment: This almost worked, but it is sending the submit into loop again

Comment: I have added the answer below, if you down voted me please undo it as this can help people. Check the answer as correct too please.